# After giving style as display block not working

Tags: html, css

Hi in the html design after adding display as inline block then also logo and text both are not displaying in a single line

```css
.logo img {
    border-width: 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: left;
}
.logo-text {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
      <img src="images/logo.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="logo-text">
      <h1>Tagore English School</h1>
   <h1>New Millennium High School</h1>
   <h3>"IMPARTING CONCRETE EDUCATION IS OUR MOTTO"</h3>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the `logo` div `inline-block` also:

```
.logo {
 display:inline-block;
 }
```

```css
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
}
.logo img {
  border-width: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: left;
}
.logo-text {
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-50-50-7.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="logo-text">
  <h1>Tagore English School</h1>
  <h1>New Millennium High School</h1>
  <h3>"IMPARTING CONCRETE EDUCATION IS OUR MOTTO"</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues here, `clear:both;` which will clear the `.logo` and you'll also need to apply the display property to both divs as they are by their nature block elements.

Then you'll need to position your logo using float and margins.

As a side note, `vertical-align` accepts a vertical property `top, middle, bottom` not a horizontal property `left, center, right`

```css
.logo {
  float: left;
  margin: 30px 30px 0 0;
}

.logo,
.logo-text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo img {
  border-width: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.logo-text {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="images/logo.png" />
</div>
<div class="logo-text">
  <h1>Tagore English School</h1>
  <h1>New Millennium High School</h1>
  <h3>"IMPARTING CONCRETE EDUCATION IS OUR MOTTO"</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: but it shold be equally but in the above code logo was displaying little bit down

Comment: @care567 Ive updated my answer for you, this should fit your requirements now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make image div display inline.so make the logo div display inline to display both things.

1. Add this to your css

   .logo {
    display:inline-block;
    }